# Creating a .bashrc function with encapsulated commands

Tags: macos, bash, bashrc

I'm trying to create a function in `.bashrc` to shortcut my MAMP commands. I want to do something like this:

`mamp config`

- Opens up MAMP's `httpd.conf` file for editing.

`mamp restart`

- Restarts the MAMP server.

I created a function in `.bashrc` called `mamp()`:

```
function mamp {
  if [$1 == "config"]; then
    nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
  fi

  if [$1 == "restart"]; then
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl restart
  fi
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I get this error `-bash: [config: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add spaces in the `if` tests,

e.g.

```
if [ $1 == "config" ]; then
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That took care of it. I didn't realize it was that picky about spacing.

Comment: You are welcome.  spacing around `[` and `]` helps bash with the parsing of the statement.

Comment: @zakang: Well, `[` is a command. Putting a space between `[` and `$1` is just like putting a space between `mamp` and `config` in `mamp config`.

Comment: @grawity: That's good to know. I work with JavaScript on a daily basis, and it's much looser with stuff like this, so I just thought it was a formatting preference.

Comment: I'd also make sure you have a parameter. `[ $1 == "config" ]` will choke somewhat cryptically if there is no $1 parameter. Putting `[ $# -ne 0 ] && return` will do so.